# How do I get an extended child model to respond to changes on the parent?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have something that looks like this:

```
Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({});
Child = Parent.extend({});
```

Is there an event that I can listen for in the child that is fired when there are changes in the parent?

Comment: If Parent and Child are the prototype objects and not instances, you couldn't really listen to the other? This seems more like a job for the views/controllers rather than the models if you're looking for firing events. As it is, Child would inherit anything added from the Parent prototype, but not its instances.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misunderstanding how backbone models work.  In this case you are "defining" the model "classes".  The individual instances of the models that you define (new model) are not necessarily related in any way.

If however you have prototypal values instead of methods, then a change in the prototypal value would automatically be changed in other instances of the model.  But this is quite different from the way backbone stores model instances values with the associated eventing.

Is there a use case that you are trying to achieve?